# Multi-tenancy with and IdentityServer 4 and Angular with oidc-client

Tags: angular, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

We are developing a multi-tenanted application using Angular 6. Each tenant accesses the application using their sub-domains, say, `client1.app.com`, `client2.app.com` etc.

For authentication purposes, we are using IdentityServer 4. We have followed steps similar to the ones mentioned at: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html.

All works well - the point we are stuck on is how do we specify the `redirect_uri` in the Angular client application.

As you are well aware, the `redirect-uri` is used by the Identity Server to return back the authentication results and info. As per the `oidc-client` library the `redirect_uri` is a string and we cannot specify multiple values. However, in our case based on the client's sub-domain the `redirect-uri` will differ and has to be dynamic.

Has anyone encountered similar situation? Am I overlooking anything? Any pointers to solve the above will greatly help.

Thanks
Sushil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the `redirect_uri` in your client to be resolved from the host (using `window.location` or whatever solution you want to use here). Then every tenant will pass this URI when accessing Identity Server.

On the Identity Server side, in the Client object, the `RedirectUris` property is a collection, so there you should add all your tenants' redirect uri's (don't forget the `PostLogoutRedirectUris` too).

Comment: Thanks - this is what we have done currently - does any know if it has any security flaws?

Comment: What do you mean by that? If you think it makes it less secure - no it doesn't. The level of security is the same as it is with only one instance.

Comment: Thanks @m3n7alsnak3